# Proper DateTime Format on Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

I have problem with read a datetime format like this : `7/1/2014 6:02:09 AM` , my goal is I want to compare some date in query oracle by to_date function but it seems different with the format, like there are no zero in the month, day, and hours.

my thought for the better query is like this `to_date('7/1/2014 6:02:09 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')`

but seems like I have wrong format for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `to_date('7/1/2014 6:02:09 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')` returns a valid **`DATE`** value, so where is your problem?

Comment: I'm asking the format date above because my MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM was false

Comment: Do you want to convert a `DATE` into a string and convert this with another string? Do the opposite, convert the string into a `DATE` and compare then the date values - this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this format instead:

```
to_date('07-01-2014 12:15','MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI'))
```

Comment: Thanks for edit @Krumia I'm from mobile phone and posting codes isn't simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the format,
I have to change first the AM PM format to 24 hours timestamp :

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

thank you all audiences :)